# Elongated shapes in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

How would one make an elongated shape in Adobe Illustrator? Much like the  icon I listed below. I've circle which parts of the icon I'm thinking of. Larger rounded shape at the top and smaller rounded shape at the bottom. Both of those two shapes connected to make one shape.

[image]

- Image courtesy of [Sandor](https://dribbble.com/shots/2992325-Tool-Combination)

Answer (score 2):

- Draw the base anchor by just clicking once with the Pen Tool.
- Draw the top anchor by click-dragging with the pen tool
- Click the base anchor again.

[image]

If you then want to curve the bottom anchor a bit, with the Pen Tool still active, hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click-drag on top of the bottom anchor to pull out handles, and add a smooth curve to it.

//Option #B

- Draw an ellipse
- Select the bottom anchor
- Double-click the Scale Tool in the Toolbar and enter a reduction percentage
- Select the 2 middle anchors and move them upwards until you get the shape you want.

[image]

//Option 3

- Draw a Circle
- Using the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow) click and drag the bottom anchor downward

[image]

Comment: The "option" formatting was intentional because none of these methods is better than the other. Really it's just 3 different methods in no particular order.